# Dealing with duplicate indexes in pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a pair of time series in pandas, and a function that will look at small time slices of them and extract rows as being the same according to some criteria on the values in the rows. This function returns a tuple of the two dataframes with these matched rows removed and placed in a list of new dataframes.

The problem, I have realized, is that its just possible (though very unlikely) that a dataframe might contain two identical indexes, in that case, the drop command will remove both the original index and the row with a duplicate index, which will occasionally result in incorrect results.

Note that the two dataframes will both be small, less than 10 rows in all circumstances, so terrible O() behavior is fine.

I have thought of two workarounds, but I am not sure exactly how to implement them.

(1) Refer to the rows by integer locations, but drop does not appear to work with integer specifications. I could do:

```
df.reset_index().drop(1).set_index(["Thingy", "Other"])
```

to reset the multi-index, but that relies on me knowing the names of the other index levels, and feels really slow/hacky. Although I guess its probably fine.

(2) Check for duplicate indexes and then add some tiny timedelta to them, so they would no longer be duplicates but i cannot figure out how to do this elegantly either.

Here is a simple example of such a function:

```
def extract_pairs(df_first, df_second, threshold=0.0):
    name1 = df_first.name
    name2 = df_second.name
    results = []
    flag = False
    for index1, row1 in df_first.iterrows():
        for index2, row2 in df_second.iterrows():
            val1 = row1.get_value("SIZE")
            val2 = row2.get_value("SIZE")
            if val1*(1-threshold) <= val2 <= val1*(1+threshold) :
                row1.loc["Name"] = name1
                row2.loc["Name"] = name2
                results.append(pd.DataFrame([row1, row2], index=[index1, index2]))
                flag = True
                break
        if flag:
            break

    if flag:
        df_first = df_first.drop(index1) #May remove more than one entry!
        df_first.name = name1
        df_second = df_second.drop(index2) #May remove more than one entry!
        df_second.name = name2
        df_first, df_second, new_results = extract_pairs(df_first, df_second)
        results.extend(new_results)

    return df_first, df_second, results
```

==================Example===============

Suppose the input dataframes were:

```
Index SIZE          Index SIZE 
 A     5              B    5     
 A     7              C    6
```

When called the desired output is three frames:

```
Index SIZE          Index SIZE      Index Name Size      
 A     7              C     6         A    Foo  5
                                      B    Bar  5
```

But the actual output of the function as given is :

```
Index SIZE          Index SIZE      Index Name Size      
 EMPTY DF             C     6         A    Foo  5
                                      B    Bar  5
```

Because the drop(index1) line drops *all* rows with index A.

Comment: Sorry what are you wanting to achieve here? You want to get rid of the additional duplicates? which is what `drop_duplicates` does or you want to keep them and add some discriminate value to the duplicates?

Comment: i want the df_first.drop(index1) to drop *only* the row which is selected by the broken for loops. As it is, if two indexes are the same, drop will also drop the the other row. I only want to drop the row that I have identified as being part of a pair.

Comment: @phil_20686 what do you want to happen if `threshold = 1`?  That is, when row X is close to (i.e. within `threshold` of) rows Y and Z but Y and Z are not close to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can do the following steps:

1. use `reset_index()` to put the index to your data frame
2. select the rows after your criterion, use `.index` to return the row position
3. `drop()` the rows by position
4. use `set_index(index)`, set the "index" column back as your index

I made the following example, I want to **delete all rows where column A > 0**, the returned rowindex will be [1,2,2], but the name of fourth row is also "2", Is this your problem?

```
# Generate the dataset
np.random.seed(1)
rowname = [1,2,2,2,4,4]
myDf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=rowname, columns=list('ABCD'))
print myDf
>>>
          A         B         C         D
 1  1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172 -1.072969
 2  0.865408 -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207
 2  0.319039 -0.249370  1.462108 -2.060141
 2 -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769 -1.099891
 4 -0.172428 -0.877858  0.042214  0.582815
 4 -1.100619  1.144724  0.901591  0.502494

# put your rowindex to your dataframe
newDf = myDf.reset_index()

# get the index from the new dataframe, drop them and set the index back to your result
result = newDf.drop(newDf[newDf.A>0].index).set_index("index")
print result

>>>           A         B         C         D
index                                        
 2     -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769 -1.099891
 4     -0.172428 -0.877858  0.042214  0.582815
 4     -1.100619  1.144724  0.901591  0.502494
```